# Java applet authenticity issue

Tags: java, applet, security, reverse-engineering, japplet

I implemented an applet in java to authenticate users at my website by the usage of MIFARE cards and everything is working good. However I am concerned about the applet's authenticity, in other words, how can I guarantee that is my applet who is communicating with my website ? and is not a script-kiddie that made an applet that simulates my applets behaviours in order to hack into my website.

I am having some difficulties to imagine a way to guarantee my applet authenticity to my website since this applet is developed in Java and code reverse engineering is possible.

best regards,

Comment: If your applet is signed then the user would be notified that the applet is untrusted.

Comment: this signature cannot guarantee if it is my applet that is accessing my website. :/

Comment: How do you verify that any request that comes into your webserver is authentic? Usually SSL, right? The only solution that would _guarantee_ authenticity is public key signing of the data.

Comment: The problem is that applets are stored in the client side so SSL cannot be used to prove authenticity. Even if I store the priv. and pub. key inside the applet the malicious user could use reverse engineering to obtain these keys.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to be sure that a socket was opened by any one piece of software.  I think the best thing you can do is have your server thoroughly validate everything that comes over the connection.